# Restart requirement for Apache Ambari custom service

Tags: service, restart, ambari

Currently, every time I change some property on a service (lets say,Hive), the Ambari UI will ask me to Restart the service and it's components. However, the same won't happen with custom services. Is there some tag that needs to be added to a given property to trigger this behavior? Is there a documentation somewhere about it?

I'm using Ambari 2.7.3.0 with HDP-3.1.0.0-78.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Evandro Teixeira

Inside of custom services should be a metainfo file  with the following value:

```
<restartRequiredAfterChange>true</restartRequiredAfterChange>
```

Depending on the service, there can be other references between different components, including even the order of restarting.  There are also some big stack configuration files (in the raw stack folder and/or in m-packs) that have similar functionality for behaviors in ambari.  The documentation here is very limited so I recommend comparing your custom services with others.  For example I learned a ton about Management Packs by reverse engineering NiFI Managementpack.   I also learned a lot more doing same with Hortonworks created ELK Management Pack.

You can find most of my management pack and custom services work on my GitHub:

https://github.com/steven-matison?tab=repositories

The ELK Management Pack (elasticsearch_mpack-3.4.0.0-0/common-services/ELASTICSEARCH/6.3.2/metainfo.xml) is where I referenced the restartRequiredAfterChange.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but adding the tag to my metainfo file has changed nothing at all. Ambari still won't ask for a service restart.

Comment: Did you add it in the right place?  Re-install service or management pack?  Restart ambari?   Did you also inspect the other artifacts related to stack, service(s)?  Ambari Server and Agent will cache service info files, so after a change you have to be sure to delete cache, full re-install service, restart things, etc.

Comment: Yeah, sorta. What I did was to stop and delete the service from the Ambari UI, them stop the server, remove the "archives.zip" file in my service, insert the tag, and proceed to restart ambari-server and reinstall my custom service from scratch. Usually this will be enough to see any changes in my service, but the tag seemed to have no effect at all. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Returning here just to let you know that adding the line worked. For some reason the Restart button started to appear after three or four re-installations of the same service. No idea why tho. Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: Fun with ambari cache...  glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Could you create a tutorial to custom Spark 3 in ambari 2.7.4 hdp 3.1.4? @steven-matison